# External javascript array initializing

Tags: javascript, html

I have an external client in a js file.

```
function client(Id,userName,code,type, firstName, SurName, address, phoneNum, Email)
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.code = code;
    this.firstName=firstName;
    this.SurName=SurName;
    this.ddress=address;        
    this.phoneNum=phoneNum;
    this.Email =Email;
    this.clientAccounts = [];

    this.addAccount = function(account)
    {
        this.clientAccounts.push(account);
    };

    }
```

and I have an html page. In it I have a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myClients =new Array();
myClients[0]= {firstName:"John", SurName: "Doe" ,Id:11,Password:1234, Address:"Some where over the rainbow", Pnumber:0523456789, Email:"yeah@gmail.com", Type: "regular"};
var account = new account(232, "young");
var deposit = new depositAccount(232, "young", 1000, 2555);
myClients[0].addAccount(deposit);

//clientAccounts.push(myClients[0]);
</script>
```

Each client I initialize should have multiple accounts. Now I'm not sure how do I set the account array of the client. should it be a part of the constructor(inside the parentheses)?
Because right now I can't use this array or get its data (I'm trying using another js file).

Comment: wish i understood what you were asking.

Comment: It's supposed to be like oop. How do I make the array a property of client?

Comment: myClients[0].Accounts = [];  is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I just saw the first answer, so you are just asking how to create an instance of Client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you actually make use of the constructor:

```
myClients[0] = new client(11, "username", 1234, "regular", "John", "Doe", "Somewhere over the rainbow", "0523456789", "yeah@gmail.com");
```

Then the "addAccount" method should work. 
Otherwise you just have an object with some properties(attributes), but not of the class client.